# why is visual studio 2010 running very slow in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

couldn't find any topic which is similar to mine. while in debug mode, each time i press on the F10 button(to preform one step) it takes about 4-5 seconds the complete the command.
im running a C++ ATL project.

thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual studio app running extremly slow with debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362895/visual-studio-app-running-extremly-slow-with-debug)

Answer (score 3):

I recently did a winupdate(20120508) and Visual studio 2010 seemed to be really slow debugging afterwards with a 1 minute delay after compile-to-runDebug lag, then when the debug program exited, another 1 minute delay to get control again of visual studio. I did clean all, but no joy.

Solution: I manually deleted the large *.sdf and *.suo files in my project/solution and rebuilt. Issue went away magically.

Not sure why, but something was out of sync, corrupted, or incompatible with the update and needed to be blown away manually.