# Visual Studio C++ Disable debugging in specific parts of code

Tags: debugging, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have a operation in my project which takes around **2 minutes** in debugging mode and less than **a second** in release mode. (If it matters, it's a function that writes a lot to a vector).

Obviously it's nearly impossible to use my application while in debugging mode due to the terrible performance that piece of code is causing.

So my question is: Is it possible to enable performance optimizations and disable debugging for a specific file or class? If not, any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: My first reaction would be to enable debug information in release mode, and debug that way. You do encounter a surprise now and again, but much more often than not, it's just fine.

Comment: You can also think about a mock object (#ifdef DEBUG_).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631609/why-is-this-code-100-times-slower-in-debug

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple aspects that affect performance:

Optimization (as you noted). You can specify optimization on a per
file level using Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization. You can also
use `#pragma optimize` as described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

Additional code that is only executed in the DEBUG configuration, like Checked Iterators; you can control them via _SECURE_SCL or _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx

Also, you can unconditionally improve the performance of your code, for example, by reserving required space in your vector upfront to avoid reallocation.